# How to select a search result on first click in react native

Tags: react-native

This is a very common pattern that can be seen in apps Like facebook, twitter, google etc. The user has a text search text input field that render a list of results, than the user select one result and is redirected to the necessary page.

I am trying to implement something like this in react native but i am facing a problem where the user needs to actually make two clicks to select select the desired result. One to release the text input focus and another to actually make a successful click in the  result list. How can i make possible to select the result in first click?

```
    <View style={tw`flex-row items-center bg-white w-full px-3`}>
        <FontAwesome name="search" size={20} color="gray" />
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Search..."
            onChangeText={(text) => setSearchValue(text)}
            value={searchValue}
            style={tw`bg-white p-2 bg-white relative`}
        />
    </View>

    {cars.length > 0 && (
        <View style={tw`bg-white p-1 bg-white opacity-95 z-10 absolute top-10 w-full`}>
            {!carOnly && (
                <FlatList
                    data={brands}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <Pressable
                            onPress={() => {
                                handleBrandSelection(item)
                            }}
                        >
                            <View style={tw`flex-row gap-2 items-center p-2`}>
                                <View style={tw`w-15 h-8 items-center`}>
                                    {item.document.mark && (
                                        <Image
                                            style={{
                                                flex: 1,
                                                width: undefined,
                                                height: undefined,
                                                resizeMode: 'contain',
                                                alignSelf: 'stretch',
                                            }}
                                            source={{
                                                uri: `${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_IMAGES_URL}/${item.document.mark}-sm.png`,
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                </View>
                                <View>
                                    <Text key={item.document.id}>{item.document.name}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </Pressable>
                    )}
                />
            )}
```

Comment: Is your component wrapped in a scrollview, if so you could use the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` attribute to have the keyboard ignore the click and should then allow your item to be clicked directly.

Comment: It isn't a scrollview, sadly. There is also another similar component that lives in the nav top bar and has the results rendered in a page view and needs a similar behaviour